# Shell Script for Searching text with variable and replace it with content

Tags: shell

im new to shell script, but i need something to search a file with any given variable, and if the file contains this variable replace it with the variables alias

the text would be some thing like:

```
74304050 = +4574304050@voip1.local
74304051 = +4574304051@voip1.local
20304050 = +4520304050@voip2.local
20304051 = +4520304051@voip2.local
```

so if i use call the shell script with 20304050 i get +4520304050@voip1.local

how can this be done, i need it for calling aliases and rewriting them in opensips config file?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because if the first field is 20304050, the third is `+4520304050@voip2.local` not voip1.local.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit underspecified, but does this do what you want?

```
awk -V number=20304050 '$1 == $number { print $3 }' file
```